# learning linux for advanced users

Tags: 14.04, partitioning

I am a student of computer science and am pretty experienced with windows and have used ubuntu server for a few small programming exercises, but that's it for linux. I am looking for a comprehensive guide for everything from creating each partition for manually installing ubuntu on to using apt-get, apt-add, etc and all important/useful things for an advanced user or programmer or whatever to know. I don't mean the kind of guide that just tells you what to do, but also WHY. When I say comprehensive I mean EVERYTHING.

Thanks

Comment: Voting to close as too broad. Consider using [the forums](http://ubuntuforums.com) or [Discourse](http://discourse.ubuntu.com) for such open-ended questions.

Comment: This question in its current form is infinitely broad and not answerable at all within the scope of the site set out in the Help Center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know, way too broad a Q, but...

- Just read through all the http://help.ubuntu.com pages
- Debian's Documentation https://www.debian.org/doc/
- Debian's wiki https://wiki.debian.org/
- And Arch's https://wiki.archlinux.org pages are excellent, most tools there are available here too
- Don't forget to read all the `man` pages, maybe `info` too

Or this site looks promising, though might be getting a little dated & "text-only":

- The Linux Documentation Project http://tldp.org/

And see you next *decade* when you're done with those :-)

Comment: TLDP is good but pretty dated. Some of their recommendations need revising.

Comment: I thought it looked pretty "low res" or "text only", not that it's bad (especially for a text-only server), but I prefer the Ubuntu/Arch or Debian pages. I'll edit, thanks

Comment: oh that's not a flaw. It's just that the guides are extensive and few (the ABS, for example) are consistently updated.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and I apologize for the broad question. I didn't really think there would be just one answer.It's just kind of frustrating when you try to find an answer and everyone just tells you how but not why... to me, the why is important

Comment: @Errett We don't mind answering the why's independently. You can find many such questions both here and on [unix.se].

Comment: The stackexchange.com sites are funny sometimes. More specific questions (even "why"'s) that can be answered a few different ways are a better "fit." Web searches may be best for these types.

Answer (score 0):

a) So, welcome here...

b) http://tldp.org/

c) Just Google..

There's too much for a single source.

Comment: You could just put the link too... maybe I'll add it to my answer if you don't mind